# Keeping only .class and .properties file in WEB-INF/classes folder

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven

I am porting my current java EE project to maven. I was working on the folder structure of the war that is being created by maven, somehow got stuck.

Maven copies all my files inside webapps, including .css, .js etc inside my WEB-INF/classes folder. I have kept a different folder resources for them, and want just .class and .properties files to be copied inside the classes folder.

Any ideas how can I achieve this ?

-- Adding more data --

using

```
 <webResources>
<resource>
<directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
<targetPath>resources</targetPath>
<includes>
<include>**/*.*</include>
</includes>
</resource>
 </webResources>
```

creates a resource folder inside my war and keeps all those files inside the resource folder, but somehow a copy of them are also created inside WEB-INF/classes

Comment: Where are your .css and .js resources located in your directory structure ?

Comment: they are located inside src\main\resources

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure the `maven-war-plugin` to exclude some files from the packaging. Check the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html) for that.

However, usually you keep your web resources outside the classpath (thus not in `src/main/resources`) in the `webapp` directory of your application.

The resources are copied in the `classes` directory because the `src/main/resources` is destinated to receive files that you want to be available on the classpath (`properties` files, xml configuration files, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

As @benzonico mentioned, you should be keeping your `webapp` resources in `src/main/webapp` and not `src/main/resources`.  If you are unable to change that, you could add something similar to the following to exclude the `js` and `css` files from getting copied to classes folder.

```
 <build>
    ...
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>*.css</exclude>
          <exclude>*.js</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
      ...
    </resources>
    ...
  </build>
```